# group differences in proportions

Tags: proportion, group-differences

Participants are assigned to 1 of 2 conditions. Each participant is presented with 10 candidates and asked to select 3 candidates from this pool. Across conditions, the 10 candidates always consist of 7 right-handed and 3 left-handed candidates.

Of the 3 candidates selected by each participant, I want to know how many of those candidates are left-handed. Therefore, values can be 0, 1, 2, 3. Or: 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1.

My main question is whether the average proportion of left-handed candidates differs between the two conditions. What is the appropriate test for this? Can I use a Mann-Whitney U test?

Comment: I assume "1/2" should be "1/3" ?

Comment: Such a test would not have access to sufficient information.  The missing piece, which is essential, is the number of right-handed candidates in each pool.  Do you have those data, too?

Comment: My initial thoughts:  1) You might assume the selection method to be random.  That is, the fact that there are 10 participants who select 3 people each won't matter.  It would be the same as selecting 30 at random. If this assumption holds, I would think you could just do a chi-square test of association on the 2 x 2 table:  ( Condition1 vs. Condition2 ) x (right vs. left).

Comment: 2) On the other hand, if you want to treat "participant" as the experimental unit --- as the question suggests --- then Mann-Whitney U seems like a potentially reasonable approach.  However, given the fact that like 90% of people are considered right-handed, the range of values for right-handedness across participants might be limited.  That is, most of the values for right-handedness might be 2/3 or 1.  In this case I might be tempted to use something else.

Comment: @whuber, for each condition, we keep the number of right-handed candidates in the pool constant. so for example's sake, lets say we have 8 right-handed and 3 left-handed people that we present to participants in each condition. We want to know what proportion of the 3 selected candidates are left-handed.